# Как подключить картинку через <img>?

Tags: html, img, изображения

Мне аж стыдно такое спрашивать. Не получается подключить картинку ( Что я уже только не писал в `<img src="">` Может кто подскажет..для error 404.php
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В каком файле подключаете? index.php?

Comment: Страница, в которую вы пишете img src, по какому адресу хоть открывается? И сама картинка по какому адресу открывается?

Comment: uk/5461846465 получаю 404.php вот сюда

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему:

```
<img src="/images/404_04.png" />
```

Но многое зависит от настроек веб-сервера.

Comment: не получилось (

Comment: Какая ошибка в логах сервера?

Answer (score 0):

Вот получше:

```
    <img src="uk/public/images/404_04.png">
```

Вот и все.